# Why is jest test giving failing and giving a timed out error but a 404 error when the parameters are switched?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, jestjs

I want to start incorporating testing with Jest in my projects but I'm having a hard time getting this test to work. When I run it I get this error thrown.

```
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

       5 |
       6 |
    >  7 | test('Create a new user', async()=>{
         | ^
       8 |
       9 |    await request(app).post('/').send({
      10 |         name:'alex',

      at Object.test (tests/user.test.js:7:1)
```

The code in the test file looks like this

```
const app = require('../app');
const usersRoute = require('../routes/users');
const request = require('supertest');



test('Create a new user', async()=>{

   await request(app).post('/').send({
        name:'alex',
        email:"a@gmail.com",
        password:"1234567",
        role:"admin"
    }).expect(201);

})
```

My app.js file looks like this

```
const express = require("express");
const colors = require('colors');
const errorHandler = require('./middleware/error');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const localdb = require('./db/bootcampDB');
const fileupload = require('express-fileupload');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

//ROUTES

const reviews = require('./routes/reviews');
const auth = require('./routes/auth')
const bootcamps = require('./routes/bootcamps');
const courses = require('./routes/courses')
const users = require('./routes/users');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json())

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
}

localdb();

app.use(fileupload())

//SET static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/api/v1/bootcamps', bootcamps);
app.use('/api/v1/courses', courses);
app.use('/api/v1/auth', auth);
app.use('/api/v1/users', users);
app.use('/api/v1/reviews', reviews);

app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(errorHandler)

module.exports = app;
```

server.js file

```
const app = require('./app');

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000

const server = app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${port}`.yellow.bold);
})


process.on('unhandledRejection',(err, promise)=>{
    console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`.red);
    
    //Close server
    server.close(()=>{
        process.exit(1)
    })
})
```

This particular test needs to go through the "/api/v1/users" route that looks like this

```
router.route('/').get(advancedResults(User), getUsers).post(createUsers);
```

That line of of code is in file called uses.js that is in a folder called routes.

user.js file

```
 const express = require('express');
const {getUsers,getSingleUsers,createUsers, deleteUsers, updateUsers} = require('../controllers/users');
const User = require('../models/user');
const router = express.Router({mergeParams:true});

const {protect, authorize} = require('../middleware/auth')
const advancedResults = require('../middleware/advancedResults');

router.use(protect);
router.use( authorize('admin'))

router.route('/').get(advancedResults(User), getUsers).post(createUsers);

router.route('/:id').get(getSingleUsers).put(updateUsers).delete(deleteUsers);


module.exports = router;
```

The method it self is in a file called user.js that is in a controllers folder. It looks like this

```
// @desc   Create user
// @route  POST /api/v1/auth/users
// @access Private/Admin

exports.createUsers = asynHandler(async(req, res, next)=> {
    const user = await User.create(req.body)
     
    res.status(201).json({success:true, data: user})
});
```

One of the things I've done is change what's being passed into requests. For example if I pass in `'/api/v1/users'` I don't get the timed error I get this error

```
   expected 201 "Created", got 404 "Not Found"

      12 |         password:"1234567",
      13 |         role:"admin"
    > 14 |     }).expect(201);
         |        ^
      15 |
      16 | })
      17 |

      at Object.expect (tests/user.test.js:14:8)
      ----
      at Test._assertStatus (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:252:14)
      at node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:308:13
      at Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:285:13)
      at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:164:23)
      at localAssert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:120:14)
      at node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:125:7
      at Test.fn [as callback] (node_modules/superagent/src/node/index.js:924:3)
      at IncomingMessage.callback (node_modules/superagent/src/node/index.js:1153:18)
```

This makes me even more confused because I thought I was telling the program to create data, not find it. If anyone can help me understand Jest and what's going on here I would greatly appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out actually someone else helped me figure it out. The error was in the routing. Jest didn't know what route to run and would just timedout when it couldn't locate the route. My request should've been written like this

```
test('Create a new user', async () => {

    const response = await request(app)
      .post(`/api/v1/auth/register`)
      .send({
        name: 'alex',
        email: 'a@gmail.com',
        password: '1234567',
        role: 'admin',
      }).expect(201);
  });
```

auth.js routes file

```
const express = require('express');
const {register, login, getMe, getAllUser,forgotPassword, resetPassword, updateDetails, updatePassword} = require('../controllers/auth');
const { protect } = require('../middleware/auth');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/allusers',getAllUser);
router.post('/register', register);
router.post('/login', login);
router.get('/me', protect, getMe);
router.post('/forgotPassword', forgotPassword);
router.put('/resetpassword/:resettoken', resetPassword);
router.put('/updatedetails', protect, updateDetails);
router.put('/updatepassword', protect, updatePassword);


module.exports = router;
```